Flask doesn't activate debug mode and update code
I'm trying to start working with flask, but don't understand nothing. I started with this basic code:
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
   return 'Hello World'

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run()

But if i want to update this string I don't see nothing new. New code:
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')        
def hello_world():
    response = make_response('Hello World! New message')
    response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'no-store'
    return response

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("debugging")
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)

Debug=True, but nothubg happens and I see "Debug mode: off" in terminal. I delete browser cache but nothing new again. What should I do?

Ensure that FLASK_ENV environment variable is set to development. this activates the debug mode and auto reloads the app when you make changes.
in terminal set the environment varable before running your app
export FLASK_ENV=development

or in Windows
set FLASK_ENV=development

Restart the server.

I don’t if it is right, but I replace my file. It was near Flask folder, but I put it near venv folder into Flask folder. And it works. Wow

Sometimes Flask can be picky about where files are placed. Settings the FLASK_ENV variable to development is still good idea because it helps with debugging and auto reloads your app whenever you make changes. it might save you some trouble in the future if anything similar happens again!.
of this was helpful, please mark it as answered - it could help others too!
